# QlineEdit widget not displayed according to QTDesigner definition

Tags: pyqt5

I'm still practicing with pyQT5 and I'm facing this issue: I created a form with QTDesigner and then converted in .py using pyuic5.
Now, if I preview the form in QTDesigner, it looks like the first image shown below (which is OK).

After the conversion in .py, when I launch the program, it looks like the second image shown below where the 2 fields 'Descrizione CDL' and 'Descrizione' are not displayed correctly. As I simply converted the file without changing anything in the code, I don't have any idea why the form looks like different.

I post also the code even though it's the pure result of the conversion from .ui to .py as no changes have been made.

[image]

[image]

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(776, 459)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(13, 13, 721, 434))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setLabelAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.formLayout.setFormAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.lE_cdl = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lE_cdl.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lE_cdl.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lE_cdl.setObjectName("lE_cdl")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lE_cdl)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lE_descCDL = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lE_descCDL.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lE_descCDL.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lE_descCDL.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(1000, 0))
        self.lE_descCDL.setMaxLength(32767)
        self.lE_descCDL.setObjectName("lE_descCDL")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lE_descCDL)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lE_tipo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lE_tipo.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lE_tipo.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lE_tipo.setObjectName("lE_tipo")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lE_tipo)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.lE_desc2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lE_desc2.setObjectName("lE_desc2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lE_desc2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.dSB_costi = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.dSB_costi.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.dSB_costi.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.dSB_costi.setObjectName("dSB_costi")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dSB_costi)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_7)
        self.sB_troncone = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sB_troncone.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.sB_troncone.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.sB_troncone.setObjectName("sB_troncone")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.sB_troncone)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_6)
        self.sB_barra_utile = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sB_barra_utile.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.sB_barra_utile.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.sB_barra_utile.setObjectName("sB_barra_utile")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.sB_barra_utile)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_9)
        self.sB_sovrametallo = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sB_sovrametallo.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.sB_sovrametallo.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.sB_sovrametallo.setObjectName("sB_sovrametallo")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.sB_sovrametallo)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_8)
        self.dSB_cambio_utensile = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.dSB_cambio_utensile.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.dSB_cambio_utensile.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.dSB_cambio_utensile.setObjectName("dSB_cambio_utensile")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dSB_cambio_utensile)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(9, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_11)
        self.sSB_tempo_carico_auto = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sSB_tempo_carico_auto.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.sSB_tempo_carico_auto.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.sSB_tempo_carico_auto.setObjectName("sSB_tempo_carico_auto")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(9, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.sSB_tempo_carico_auto)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(10, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_10)
        self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass.setObjectName("dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(10, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(11, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_13)
        self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man.setObjectName("dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(11, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(12, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_12)
        self.sB_nr_giri_max = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sB_nr_giri_max.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.sB_nr_giri_max.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.sB_nr_giri_max.setObjectName("sB_nr_giri_max")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(12, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.sB_nr_giri_max)
        self.pb_conf = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pb_conf.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pb_conf.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.pb_conf.setFont(font)
        self.pb_conf.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pb_conf.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 144, 81);")
        self.pb_conf.setObjectName("pb_conf")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(13, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pb_conf)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Inserimento Risorse Interne"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Centro di lavoro (CDL)"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Descrizione CDL"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Tipo"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Descrizione 2"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Costi"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "Troncone (mm)"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "Barra utile (mm)"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "Sovrametallo per taglio (mm)"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Cambio utensile (s)"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "Tempo carico e scarico automatico (s)"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "Tempo riposiz. Creatore per 2° passate (s)"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("Form", "Tempo riposiz. Creatore per caricamento MANUALE"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("Form", "n° di giri max (RPM)"))
        self.pb_conf.setText(_translate("Form", "Conferma "))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>776</width>
    <height>459</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Inserimento Risorse Interne</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>13</x>
     <y>13</y>
     <width>721</width>
     <height>434</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout">
      <property name="fieldGrowthPolicy">
       <enum>QFormLayout::ExpandingFieldsGrow</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="labelAlignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="formAlignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
      </property>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Centro di lavoro (CDL)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lE_cdl">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Descrizione CDL</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lE_descCDL">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeIncrement">
         <size>
          <width>1000</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maxLength">
         <number>32767</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Tipo</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lE_tipo">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Descrizione 2</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lE_desc2"/>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Costi</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="1">
       <widget class="QDoubleSpinBox" name="dSB_costi">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Troncone (mm)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="1">
       <widget class="QSpinBox" name="sB_troncone">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="6" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Barra utile (mm)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="6" column="1">
       <widget class="QSpinBox" name="sB_barra_utile">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="7" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Sovrametallo per taglio (mm)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="7" column="1">
       <widget class="QSpinBox" name="sB_sovrametallo">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="8" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Cambio utensile (s)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="8" column="1">
       <widget class="QDoubleSpinBox" name="dSB_cambio_utensile">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="9" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_11">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Tempo carico e scarico automatico (s)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="9" column="1">
       <widget class="QDoubleSpinBox" name="sSB_tempo_carico_auto">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="10" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Tempo riposiz. Creatore per 2° passate (s)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="10" column="1">
       <widget class="QDoubleSpinBox" name="dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="11" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_13">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Tempo riposiz. Creatore per caricamento MANUALE</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="11" column="1">
       <widget class="QDoubleSpinBox" name="dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="12" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_12">
        <property name="text">
         <string>n° di giri max (RPM)</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="12" column="1">
       <widget class="QSpinBox" name="sB_nr_giri_max">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="13" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pb_conf">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <bold>true</bold>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="autoFillBackground">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 144, 81);</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Conferma </string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: On ubuntu-20, Python 3.8.10, PyQt5 5.15.2, your py looks similar to designer. Could you add your version info? (with e.g. `python3 -c 'import sys, PyQt5.QtCore ; print(sys.version) ; print(PyQt5.QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)'`)

Comment: Here is the result of the command: 3.9.10 (v3.9.10:f2f3f53782, Jan 13 2022, 16:55:46) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
5.15.2

Comment: I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.2.1

Comment: Part of the problem is that you aren't using layouts consistently. Plerase post the original designer ui file.

Comment: OK. I added the ui file right below the code. Thanks for the help

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is set a layout on the top-level widget (i.e. `Form`) in qt designer, and then re-run pyuic.

Comment: @MDR see how to use [layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html), specifically "Setting A Top Level Layout".

Comment: Understood. Thanks all for your comments